# Mapping one table to more than one with a single mapping table

Tags: sql, database-design, one-to-many

Lets say I have a table EmailQueue that is used to build out emails to send to users, using several non related processes.  The Emails can contain a ever growing number of different 'content items' but for now lets just say we have News, Events, and Offers.  Each of these 'content items' are already populated in their own respective tables and will be selectively added to a users email.

Now I have a design decision to make.

**1**
I could keep with a normalized pattern and create a mapping table for each of the 'content items' that an email can contain.

```
|EmailId|NewsId| , |EmailId|OfferId| , ...
```

The main issue I see with this design is that there is a good bit of overhead every time a new 'content type' is integrated to the email system; Both in database and object mapping.

**OR**

**2**
I could create 1 mapping table that has a Type reference.

```
   |EmailId|ContentID|ContentType|
```

Of course the big issue here is that there is no referential integrity.  I feel object mapping would be much easier to handle and adding a new object only requires adding a new `ContentType` row (and of course the required object mapping code).

**Is one of these solutions better than the other?  Or is there a solution better than both of these that I am unaware of?**

I'm leaning towards using method 2, mainly because this project needs to be rapidly developed, but worried I may regret that decision down the road.

*Note: We are using subsonic as our data access ORM, which does a decent(not perfect) job of handling object graphs through keyed relations.  I will still likely need to map the active record 'content' objects to domain object though.*

Comment: So even though the processes are unrelated, is there really no way to combine your different "content types" into a single table? Something like ContentID, ContentTypeID, Content?

Comment: thats kinda what solution 2 would be doing.  I obviously wouldn't store the content itself in the table as it already exists in a table and the schema is different for each content type.